# On which Stack Exchange site should I ask question about a printer?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Recently I've bought an inkjet printer **HP Deskjet 1010** for my personal use. I've some problem with it. On which Stack Exchange site should I ask the question about my printer?

Answer (score 6):

[Super User!](https://superuser.com/)

From their [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - **computer hardware,**
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking